# Funciones y argumentos en carrito

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un curso para Js y me surgió una duda casi existencial. **adjunto el código a continuación**

```
function leerDatosCurso(curso) {

  const infoCurso = {
    imagen: curso.querySelector('img').src,
    titulo: curso.querySelector('h4').textContent,
    precio: curso.querySelector('.precio span').textContent,
    id: curso.querySelector('a').getAttribute('data-id')
  }

  añadirCarrito(infoCurso);

}

function añadirCarrito(curso) {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `

        <td><img src="${curso.imagen}"></td>
        <td>${curso.titulo}</td>
        <td>${curso.precio}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="boton-borrar" data-id="${curso.id}">X</a>
        </td>  
    `;

    //agrego este template a lista cursos

    listaCursos.appendChild(row);
}
```

No logro dilucidar lo siguiente.. para la función añadirCarrito le paso como argumento curso...todo bien hasta allí, pero porque en la función de leerDatosCursos (dentro de esta) se llama a la función añadirCarrito(**infoCurso**). si después para la función añadirCarrito uso otro parámetro.

**CUALQUIER AYUDA SIRVE PARA SEGUIR APRENDIENDO AMIGOS.**

Comment: No se si lo he entendido bien, ¿tu pregunta es porque se le pasa `infoCurso` si añadirCarrito recibe `curso`? Si es eso, el nombre que tenga la variable que se pasa es indiferente del  nombre que se define en la funcion.

Comment: Perfecto, ya que me habia enredado en ese punto...como en la funcion lerrdatoscarrito se habia creado el objeto inforcurso y despues lo pasa para la proxima funcion a utilizar ahi mori jajaj